# Route Issue in Anchor Link in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**I have route defined in the `Route.php` file like below**

```
Route::get('/SubCategories-List/{categoryID}', 'Skills\Category_Controller@SubCategories');
```

**Below is the code done in Blade for showing list of records.**

```
@foreach($Categories as $Category)
    <tr class="odd pointer">
        <td class=" last">
            <a href="{{Route('SubCategories-List', [$Category->CategoryID])}}">
                 Sub Categories
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**I am getting the following error when action method calls the blade**

> Route [SubCategories-List] not defined.

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and worked.

## **[Reference](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/190/generating-a-html-link-to-a-named-route)**

**Route in Route.php**

```
Route::get('/SubCategories-List/{categoryID}', 
           array(
                   'uses' => 'Skills\Category_Controller@SubCategories', 
                   'as'   => 'SubCategories-List'
                )
          );
```

**Anchor link in Blade**

```
{{
    Html::linkRoute('SubCategories-List', 
                  'Sub Categories', 
                  array($Category->CategoryID), 
                  array('style' => 'text-decoration: underline;'))
}}
```