# How to put route in anchor tag in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've gone through many of the articles below, which explains generating link from named route, but unable to solve my problem.

[Tutorial 1](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/190/generating-a-html-link-to-a-named-route)

[Tutorial 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561624/route-issue-in-anchor-link-in-laravel-5-2)

[Tutorial 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751866/laravel-4-blade-templating-how-to-properly-link-to-route)

Following is the defined routes:

```
Route::get('/nitsadmin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('nitsadmin.dashboard');
});
```

And I'm calling link in anchor tag:

```
<a id="index" class="navbar-brand" href="{{Html::linkRoute('/nitsadmin/dashboard')}}">
      <img src="../img/admin/nitseditorlogo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

I'm getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this quite simply with the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) helper.

Just replace your anchor tag like so:

```
<a id="index" class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/nitsadmin/dashboard')}}">
      <img src="../img/admin/nitseditorlogo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Regarding the image that you have used in there, if these were to be stored in your public folder then you could always use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) helper. This would help you turn your absolute links to in dynamic ones.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Before that I was trying `URL::route('nitsadmin/dashboard')` it was not working.

Comment: {{route('route.name')}} is preferable to this because you aren't hard coding the route and if it changes your links wont change.

Comment: @Paul very good point. This is one of those "lightbulb moments" for me - I never actually saw the value in using named routes, but this totally makes sense!

Answer (score 16):

For coders using routes names, simply they can use to() method:

```
return redirect()->to(route('dashboard').'#something');
```

In templates:

```
{{ route('dashboard').'#something' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have route like these....

```
Route::get('/nitsadmin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('nitsadmin.dashboard');
});
Route::get('/land', 'HomeController@landingPage');
Route::get('/role-permission/add',          ['as' => 'mp.rp.add',          'uses' => 'RolePermissionMapController@add']);
```

so you can link like this --

```
<a href="{{url('/nitsadmin/dashboard')}}">Click </a>
<a href="{{url('/land')}}">Click </a>
<a href="{{url('/role-permission/add')}}">Click </a>
<a href="{{route('mp.rp.add')}}">Click </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your route put name and

```
Route::get('/nitsadmin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('nitsadmin.dashboard')->name(nitsadmin.dashboard);
});
```

Go to your html where you link the url

```
<a id="index" class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('nitsadmin.dashboard')}}">
      <img src="../img/admin/nitseditorlogo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work.

```
<a href="{{ route('/cardetails', ['121','cars'] ) }}">click </a>
```

In URL it will be like this below line.

**127.0.0.1:8000/cardetails/121/cars**