# Add an anchor to Laravel redirect back

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

In a Laravel controller I have this redirect:

```
    return redirect()->back();
```

Which returns me to my previous page (say http://domain/page). However, I want to make the page jump to a particular anchor (say #section). So ultimately this page should be opened: http://domain/page#section. How can I make this happen? I tried appending the anchor to the redirect but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#whatever");
```

And remember to import it at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks!! That did it!

Comment: The `to` function also accepts the output of the `route` function (at least in Laravel 5.5), thus this is also possible for linking to a *route* with an anchor: `return redirect()->to(route('user.edit', ['user' => $user->id]) . '#myanchorid');` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41606730/2286722)

Comment: Nice, I use your code like this : `return redirect()
            ->to(URL::previous() . "#anchorDocuments")
            ->with("status", "Le fichier a bien été enregistré.");`

Answer (score 26):

You can use these helpers for laravel 5.5 and above - no imports :-)

```
return redirect()->to(url()->previous() . '#hash');
```

Answer (score 3):

Modern and more elegant solution is using the withFragment method that adds a fragment identifier to the URL:

```
return redirect()->route('your_route')->withFragment('your_hash');
```

Comment: For Laravel 7 and up, this is the cleanest way.