# Return View and land on specific anchor tag on the page from within Laravel controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel Controller I want to return a view and land the page on specific anchor tag. But I can't figure out how to write the return line/code, I tried this but that didn't work:

```
return view('viewIwantToReturn#andAnchorTag',compact(....
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to write it, so it lands on the anchor tag.
On redirect it works as expected:

```
return  redirect('viewIwantToReturn#andAnchorTag');
```

I am returning the view from within edit method that also returns an object for editing, therefore I cant just redirect back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an anchor to Laravel redirect back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839737/add-an-anchor-to-laravel-redirect-back)